# Elastic Search No query registered for [geo_bounding_box]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch records from Elastic search and i get this error as below

```
ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=exception, reason=SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed;
shardFailures {[-kDbP0fmTUa5B8v1gpgoZQ][dataintelindex_ra][0]: SearchParseException[[dataintelindex_ra]
[0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"geo_bounding_box":{"loc":
{"top_left":[-74.1,40.73],"bottom_right":
[-73.99,40.717]},"validation_method":"STRICT","type":"MEMORY","ignore_unmapped":false,"boost":1.0}}}]]];
nested: QueryParsingException[[dataintelindex_ra] No query registered for [geo_bounding_box]]; }]]]
```

My Java Code is as below

```
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("dataintelindex_ra").types("station_info");
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.geoBoundingBoxQuery("loc").setCorners(40.73,-74.1,40.717,-73.99));
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse response = elasticSearchClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        for (SearchHit searchHit : response.getHits().getHits()) {
            System.out.println("~~~~~~~~SearchHit[] searchHits~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ "+searchHit.getSourceAsString());
            
        }
```

Please let me know if i missed something while trying to index , i am new to Elastic search.

Also incase if i want to include one more criteria to my query like below

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("zoneType", ["test","oms"]));
```

Below is the result for the above query and it works fine

```
~~~~~~~~SearchHit[] searchHits~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ {"tag_datatype":"sensor","loc":[{"lat":"0","lon":"0"}],"level":1,"kml_path":"","created":"Mon Aug 10 16:02:51 IST 2020","latitude":"0","station_id":"5f312253b4c93c1d20bbbb39","longtitude":"0","tag_owner":"","description":"","zoneType":"oms","tag_network_name":"chak_network","display_name":"506020200236117-O1","supply_zone":"506020200236117-O1","outflow":null,"tag_sector":"dmameter","name":"506020200236117-O1","tag_category":"sensorstation","inflow":null,"_id":"5f312253b4c93c1d20bbbb39","tag_location":"NA","lastmod":"Mon Aug 10 16:02:51 IST 2020","status":"ACTIVE"}
~~~~~~~~SearchHit[] searchHits~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ {"tag_datatype":"sensor","loc":[{"lat":"0","lon":"0"}],"level":1,"kml_path":"","created":"Tue Aug 11 11:36:51 IST 2020","latitude":"0","station_id":"5f32357b3ccb8f51e003587e","longtitude":"0","tag_owner":"","description":"","zoneType":"village","display_name":"testvillage1","supply_zone":"testvillage1","outflow":null,"tag_sector":"dmameter","name":"testvillage1","tag_category":"sensorstation","inflow":null,"_id":"5f32357b3ccb8f51e003587e","tag_location":"NA","lastmod":"Tue Aug 11 11:36:51 IST 2020","status":"ACTIVE"}
```

how do i combine with above geoboundingbox query ? do i need to add it as a filter?

Update : Dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "test1",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.2.2",
    "build_hash" : "243243432feaga",
    "build_timestamp" : "2014-07-09T12:02:32Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.8"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Thanks in advance
Rakesh

Comment: Which ES version are you running?

Comment: Hi Val,

I have updated the post with my Java Dependency and also the elastic search version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're running ES server v1.2.2 (extremely old version) with a 6.4.0 client.

So the 6.4.0 client has the `geoBoundingBoxQuery()` method, however the 1.2.2 client provides the [`geoBoundingBoxFilter()` method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.3/geo-bbox-filter.html), both are incompatible. There has been a big query/filter refactor in ES 2.x.

As a rule of thumb you should always run the same version of ES and the client library. In your case, you have a delta of several versions betweem your server and your client.

You should definitely consider upgrading your ES cluster to at least 6.4.0 or downgrade your client to 1.x.

Comment: Val, the ES server v1.2.2 is currently being used by almost 8 modules and they all use older version of ES client 1.7.4 , but one of the latest modules has been implemented using ES client 6.4 so , upgrading the ES server is not an option for me currently as it would impact all other modules. 
Is there any other way i can get the geo boundary functionality to work with the Old ES server provided i have top left and bottom right cordinates ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Val, I was able to get the new ES client to fetch results , i built the query as below and hit the server and it gave me results

10.62.62.110:9200/dataintelindex_ra/_search?pretty' -d '{"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"geo_bounding_box": {"location":{"top_left":[-74.1,40.73],"bottom_right":[-73.99,40.717]}}},{"terms": {"zoneType": ["oms"]}}]}},"size": 100000}

This works for me . 
Would you be able to help with the java query builder to form this query ? I am very new to this

Comment: Cool, it's pretty much the same code except that you need to use `FilterBuilders.geoBoundingBoxFilter()` instead